# Matching and replacing values in different columns given an ID number

Tags: r, replace, match

Suppose I have a data frame in R `df` and I am trying to replace the `Client1`, `Client2` and `Client3` numbers(IDs) by their respective `name`. I know that each number in the `Client*` vector represents a `name` given its `id` #.

```
Client1 Client2 Client3 X Y Z id Name A B C
1       2       3       y n y 1  Jay  n y n
4       1       2       y n n 4  Jack n y n
2       10      5       y n n 2  Jill y y y
8       4       2       n n y 8  Ana  y y y
```

I 'd greatly appreciate if someone knows a series of commands that would perform the following change to the frame:

```
Client1 Client2 Client3 X Y Z id Name A B C
Jay     Jill    Tom     y n y 1  Jay  n y n
Jack    Jay     Jill    y n n 4  Jack n y n
Jill    Dan     Wayne   y n n 2  Jill y y y
Ana     Jack    Jill    n n y 8  Ana  y y y
```

Hence the `Client*`column matches the id and `name`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the OP provided only a small part of the example data and in the subsequent rows, matching 'ids' for 'Dan', 'Wayne' will be found.

One option would be to `match` the 'Client' columns in the original dataset  after converting to `matrix` with the 'id' column of 'df1'.  This will provide the numeric index to be used for getting the corresponding 'Name' element from the dataset.  The output can be assigned back to the 'Client' columns to replace the numbers with the 'Name'

```
  nm1 <- grep('^Client', colnames(df1))
  df1[nm1] <- df1$Name[match(as.matrix(df1[nm1]), df1$id)]
  df1
  #  Client1 Client2 Client3 X Y Z id  Name A B C
  #1     Jay    Jill     Tom y n y  1   Jay n y n
  #2    Jack     Jay    Jill y n n  4  Jack n y n
  #3    Jill     Dan   Wayne y n n  2  Jill y y y
  #4     Ana    Jack    Jill n n y  8   Ana y y y
  #5   Wayne     Tom     Jay n n y  5 Wayne n y n
  #6     Dan    Jack     Tom y n n 10   Dan y n y
  #7     Tom    Jack    Jill n y n  3   Tom n y y
```

#### data

```
  df1 <- structure(list(Client1 = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 3L), 
  Client2 = c(2L, 
  1L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Client3 = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
  2L), X = c("y", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y", "n"), Y = c("n", "n", 
  "n", "n", "n", "n", "y"), Z = c("y", "n", "n", "y", "y", "n", 
  "n"), id = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 3L), Name = c("Jay", "Jack", 
  "Jill", "Ana", "Wayne", "Dan", "Tom"), A = c("n", "n", "y", "y", 
  "n", "y", "n"), B = c("y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "n", "y"), C = c("n", 
  "n", "y", "y", "n", "y", "y")), .Names = c("Client1", "Client2", 
  "Client3", "X", "Y", "Z", "id", "Name", "A", "B", "C"),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

NOTE: Added some more rows to have all the 'Name' corresponding to the 'number'